# I want to show name and address column, and people whose names are Ahmad and were born before 1-05-1995?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, where-clause

```
SELECT Firstname, new address
FROM 'users'
WHERE Firstname = ahmed AND birthday 1990-05-01
```

Comment: Use single quotes only for string literals and dates: `FROM users WHERE Firstname = 'ahmed' AND birthday < '1990-05-01'`

Comment: It will be very useful to your SQL skills to read the documentation to distinguish literals and identifiers: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/language-structure.html Also, some basics of SQL are available in the internet

Comment: I thank you for your interest, but I did what you suggested, but I see this error anyway. Do you have any explanation? #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''1990-05-01' LIMIT 0, 25' at line 3

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `birthdate` is of a `date`-like datatype:

```
SELECT firstname, address 
FROM users 
WHERE firstname = 'ahmed' AND birthday < '1990-05-01'
```

Single quotes stand for literal strings. Use them around the literal name and date. On the other hand, identifiers (such as table names) should not be surrounded with single quotes.